# How is an internal pullup setup with a pushbutton?

Tags: c, hardware

Hey all sorry for the rudimentary question but i have some serious problems with my pic and i think it might have to do with my misunderstanding of internal pullups

So, i have a pic18f45k22, with a portb that has weak pull up resistors enabled. If they are enabled, does that mean that i have to connect those input pins to vcc directly, and then also branch off and connect to a pushbutton as well, which is then connected to ground? Is that the proper hardware setup? I am really confused as to how this actually works...

Comment: This question belongs to the Electronics site on SE network.

Answer (score 1):

An internal pullup means that it is conntected to VCC. A weak pullup means that this happens via a quite high resistance.

So if you don't connect anything, you'll read a 1 out of this register. If you want to connect a pushbutton whose pressing you want to detect, you must connect this button to ground so that any pushing will be read as 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you

> "connect those input pins to vcc directly, ... and connect to a pushbutton as well, which is then connected to ground"

and then press the button, you'll connect the power to ground.
The smoke genie will be let out and its bye-bye chips.

Use @glglgl answer.

BTW: Posting on http://electronics.stackexchange.com is a better choice.